# Adapt page display along with jQuery result

Tags: html, jquery, django, celery

I have a Django project which executes a task and then renders a page in which I want to display different things following the state of the task.

To show an example of what I want, I have these three div, with each one being displayed for a particular task state :

```
<div id="SUCCESS"> 
    <!-- What I want to display when the execution of my task succeeded -->
</div>

<div id="FAILURE">
    <!-- What I want to display when the execution of my task failed -->
</div>

<div id="EXECUTING"> 
    <!-- What I want to display when my task is still executing -->  
</div>
```

I finally found a way of doing that by adding a `style="display:none"` on the div for the success and failure state, and updates the display of the divs when the state of task changes.

For example, at first, only the div with `id="EXECUTING"` will be displayed, and then when the task state changes to 'failed', the div with `id="EXECUTING"` will have its display attribute changed to `display:none` and the div with `id="FAILURE"` will be changed to `display:""`

The code for doing this is the following :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let task_id = '{{ task_id }}'
        updateState(task_id)

        function updateState(task_id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'scripts:task_status' task_id %}",
                type: 'GET'
            })
            .done(response => {
                 if(response.state == "FAILURE" || response.state == "SUCCESS"){
                     document.getElementById("EXECUTING").style.display = "none"
                     document.getElementById(response.state).style.display = ""
                     return 
                 }

                 else{
                     // rerun every 100 milliseconds
                     setTimeout(function() {
                         updateState(response.task_id)
                     }, 100)
                 }
            })
        }
    })
</script>
```

And the view from where the task_status is taken is this one :

```
def task_status(request, task_id):
    task = AsyncResult(task_id)
    response = {
        'task_id': task_id,
        'state': task.state,
        'info': str(task.info),
    }
    return JsonResponse(response, status=200)
```

What I want to know is, is there another way to change what's displayed on the page without using this trick of modifying the display attribute of my divs ?

That's my first time using jQuery and js so there's probably something I'm not understanding well, which is why I'm asking this.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Switching the display state is a commonly used approach to this problem. The other option is to modify the DOM directly, but your approach is usually better, because it allows you to keep content and logic separate.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, glad to have come up with what seems to be a correct answer !